# Creating a local folder that is only accessible by the app to save downloaded files in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am developing an app with react native that downloads files (images, videos, pdf etc) and show them in the app.

I need to save those downloaded files locally to use in the app.

I want to know if there is anyway to create a private folder for my app. If there is any react native libraries available.

Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately you cannot make a private folder which can be accessed only by your app. If you check any streaming apps like netflix, they use an encryption technique to secure contents within a folder. Would suggest you to look into "Digital Right Management" (DRM) techniques which are used to secure your files.

Comment: So what if I make a folder at the path my app is located. Can it be done?